# Is there any knowledge source (book, for instance) talking about cultural differences from a management point of view?

Tags: communication, culture

I'm working in global outsourcing company (and therefore interacting with several cultures) for five years, and only a few months ago I realized (in the harder way, i.e. suffering) that is VERY important to understand and have clear the differences we have between cultures.

I'm not looking for labels, but some common sense about how to deliver a clear message.

As an example, the way we say something is not as expected can vary a lot, as well as the way the other- side will get the message. In some cultures, is highly accepted to say 'your performance is horrible' and still the two sides will understand correctly the message, whilst in some cases a feedback like this could be get as personal, creating a bad mood between the two parts.

Your feedback and experiences are highly appreciated.

Comment: I did a Google search for books on cultural management and a few came up. I don't know them enough to recommend, but there seemed to be a lot on Google books and Amazon. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Perry, thanks for your contribution. My goal is to have some feedback about the material already used by our managers's peers, and for this reason I'd really love to know someone who already read a material about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This presentation](http://vimeo.com/12021592) from Robert Dempsey tackles the problem from practitioner's point of view.

Comment: Very, very, very good link, Pawel. As always, providing really valuable information for our community. BTW, your region has been highly evaluated by Dempsey, congratulations!